# Jqgrid subGridRowExpanded error object doesnt support jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a master grid and sub grid. On click of row expand , I was able to fetch the result and display. It was working fine in IE and chrome. Now I am getting   Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid' in IE10 but it works fine in chrome.

I am loading grid.locale before jqgrid src . List of scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am able to show the result in master grid. When I expand the sub grid , I am getting the error.The following is the code where I am getting the error.

```
subGrid: true,     
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
var orderid= jQuery('#tblJQGrid').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'OrderID');


Line: 291
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include more full list of JavaScript files which you use and it's order. .

One of the possible reasons could be the usage of jQuery version which has bug in IE10. For example if you would use jQuery 2.0.2 you could have the described problem. Usage of jQuery 2.0.3 or 1.10.2 will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Its working now after modifying the jquery version